# Did Jesus know where Lazarus was laid or did he not know?

Tags: john, jesus

John 11:34

“Where have you laid him?” They say to Him, “Lord, come and see”

Lazarus was buried in a tomb, which was the practice for those who could afford one. The tomb would have a slab where the body was laid. After a year, the tomb would be opened and the bones placed in an ossuary.

Lazarus was placed in the tomb of his family. Like cemeteries today burial locations were public knowledge and in some cases, made quite visible.

Matthew 23:27:

“Woe to you, scribes and Pharisees, hypocrites! For you are like whitewashed tombs which indeed appear beautiful outwardly, but inside are full of dead men’s bones and all uncleanness.

Why did Jesus ask where Lazarus was laid? Was He really ignorant of the family's tomb or was there some other reason He asked this question?

If Jesus knew, was he being disingeous when he asked?

If Jesus knew everything, then he would not need to learn anything from a teacher. But, John 8:28 show us that Jesus himself had a teacher.

John 8:28 Literal Standard Version

Jesus, therefore, said to them, “When you may lift up the Son of Man then you will know that I AM; and I do nothing of Myself, but according as My Father taught Me, these things I speak.

Jesus then taught others what the Father had taught him.

John 7:16-17 Literal Standard Version

Jesus answered them and said, “My teaching is not Mine, but His who sent Me; if anyone may will to do His will, he will know concerning the teaching, whether it is of God, or—[if] I speak from Myself.

If Jesus possess perfect knowledge why did he not know where Lazarus was laid?